# Angular 7 CLI running ng serve in my project breaks navigation for sub paths

Tags: angular, angular-cli, router, angular-cli-v7

To be clear, this is not a bug, this is a project that I inadvertently broke, I am not sure when or how.

running `ng --version` in my project:

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.4
Node: 10.14.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.2.7
```

When running `ng serve`, the app loads OK in browser at:

`http://localhost:4200`

When manually loading a path at the root, loads OK at:

`http://localhost:4200/page`

When navigating *via a link within the app* to a sub path `from a root path` of a running app, loads OK at:

```
http://localhost:4200/page/sub/path
```

**However, when attempting to load a subsequent sub path in any of the following ways:**

• refreshing an existing sub path in view in the browser

• attempting to manually enter and load a url at a sub path

• live reloading triggered by the CLI while viewing a sub path

```
http://localhost:4200/page/sub/path
```

**In error, the app attempts to load all `js` files relative to the sub path and thus, fails. The app attempts to load `runtime.js` here:**

```
http://localhost:4200/page/sub/path/runtime.js
```

when it should be loading it here:

```
http://localhost:4200/runtime.js
```

my base href is currently set to `./`

With the app running, i inspected the html source, and the script tags are formatted as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
```

I am not sure what may have broken this project. Generating a new project works without issue. I suspect possibly a recent `npm update`, but i cannot be sure when this problem started. I could have inadvertently broken navigation in my code as well.

Any idea where or how to begin troubleshooting?

Comment: Try to change your base href to /

Comment: Thank you @EvgeniyMalyutin! This did it. Now i am frustrated that i cannot remember when or why i would have changed my base href to `./`. If you want to post this as an answer i will mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Comment: Hi, @DevMIke I posted this as an answer

Comment: And he's lost in the shadows. Nice guy.
@DevMIke

Comment: sincere apologies for the delay, marked as answer, just literally been that buried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that `runtime.js` is loading from a subpath

`http://localhost:4200/page/sub/path/runtime.js`

it looks like an issue with the relative base href, try to change it to an absolute one

`<base href="/">`